# When to check for null arguments and throw ArgumentNullException

Tags: c#

I have some code like this:

```
public void someMethod (Object x)
{
   if (x == null) throw new ArgumentNullException ();

   // more code...
}
```

Should I now do this:

```
public void myMethod (Object z)
{
    someMethod (z);
}
```

Or this:

```
public void myMethod (Object z)
{
    if (z == null) throw new ArgumentNullException ();

    someMethod (z);
}
```

Note: I prefer speed of execution in this class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, all **public** methods should validate their inputs, even if it is somewhat redundant. Having said that, I often compile the more expensive validation and code contracts using conditional compilation directives so that release builds only perform the most critical diagnostics and validation.

Checking for a null argument is an important and inexpensive operation which will have only the smallest performance impact over millions of calls.

Overloaded methods that all call a common internal method might perform less checking with the knowledge that their actual implementation performs full validation.

For what it's worth, most of the BCL source code I've seen from Microsoft errs on the side of more validation, diagnostics, and contract adherence rather than less.

Comment: All *public* methods should validate their inputs; that should have been emphasized more. The real question is why both of the methods shown in the question need to be public. Most of the time, they don't.

Comment: @CodyGray - my mistake, I overwrote your edit inadvertently. I agree with choosing carefully which methods actually need to be public.

Comment: IMO the side effects of the method also have a significant impact on the validation required. If there is any chance that a method can corrupt/lose persisted data or interrupt an important user transaction, its inputs should be rigorously validated on all levels (permission, argument validity, pre/post state, etc) regardless of the overhead in doing so.

Comment: All method are public, I found something like this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182182.aspx   problem solved.

Comment: @user1109215 - yes, code analysis rules are great for answering and explaining questions like this. You can enable them to run whenever you compile in the Visual Studio project properties (if you didn't already know).

Comment: I didn't. Thank you for a tip. Can't vote up, because i have too less points.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion `someMethod` should be responsible for throwing exception if any parameter passed to it is `null`. Ideally you should not call `somemethod` from `mymethod` if `z` is `null`. You should add check for null in `myMethod` but let `somemethod` throw the exception

```
public void myMethod (Object z)
{
    someMethod (z);
}
```

I would suggest the above one. By the way these micro level optimization won't give you any significant performance boost

Comment: But if this micro optimization doesnt make nay effect, this one bellow would be more useful? I tells you the argument was bad, andsecond tells you only inner call was bad hmm

Answer (score 0):

I would go by this:

- If your method has certain requirements for the arguments passed in (like "must not be null") then it should check for that and throw if thats appropriate
- If your method calls other method it should not have to check their argument requirements as well - it's the other methods job to do that anyway. You are just duplicating code - remember DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself)

So in your case I would not check for null in `myMethod` again unless `myMethod` also relies itself on `z` not being `null`. I doubt that there are any practically relevant speed differences (remember: "premature optimization is the root of all evil")